# identify transistor

Tags: transistors, identification, npn, pnp

Does anyone know of a website or online tool to help identify a transistor-like component by its markings?

For instance, one cracked and from the pieces, I can't be sure what it used to read (partial searches like `BM 69D` or `JJ 807` didn't help, but again, we can't be sure due to the cracks).

So I've been seeking compatible drop-in replacements while soldering out a bunch of other mystery transistors from junked circuit boards, **hence I need some lookup tool, not just to ID this one.**

I learned to ID whether it's NPN or PNP using a multimeter diode test, but that doesn't help a component which has already exploded, eg. due to an ant having crawled into the wrong spot and created a high-voltage short-out, ruining the GFCI outlet from inside.

BTW should I deeply be concerned with other specs besides matching the PNP/NPN type and case size?   Of course I'll test the GFCI offline before re-installing into the trailer's AC wall grid.

Already checked  [Identify SMD transistor - top marking BC RJ](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/507665/identify-smd-transistor-top-marking-bc-rj)  and [Identify surface mount transistor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/121032/identify-surface-mount-transistor)

Comment: https://www.alldatasheet.com/view.jsp?Searchword=BT169D

Comment: As an example for a good answer, other domains have such tools freely available and they are incredibly useful, such as [pill-identifying](https://www.drugs.com/imprints.php) in medicine.  Perhaps not common for electronics?

Comment: @Marcos Uh, did you try to click the link in the first comment? That's one of the "free" tools.

Comment: @LongPham It was partially useful, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried putting the part number into a search engine? Searching "BT169" turns up a number of results identifying it as a thyristor, not a transistor; [here's](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/NXP%20PDFs/BT169_Series.pdf) a datasheet.